# Centos 7 - sshd sftp group permissions messed up after update

Tags: centos, permissions, sftp, update

`Centos` recently updated to `7.3` and there's been problems with sshd sftp group permissions. I have one user that is chrooted to it's home directory, and that user is in group `sftponly`. Then i have the /var/www directory, which has `775` permissions and owner is `apache` and owner group is `sftponly`. I have a bind link pointing from `/home/user/files/web` --> `/var/www`, so the user can access /var/www even though being chrooted to it's home directory. I can view files in /var/www with that user, but impossible to edit or add anything. This worked fine before the big `Centos` `7.3` update, and now it's stopped working. Any ideas?

Comment: Get an error message. Check your logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SFTP suddenly failing for chroot accounts on Amazon Linux](http://serverfault.com/questions/816219/sftp-suddenly-failing-for-chroot-accounts-on-amazon-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1398569) and it will be fixed in the next update. Before that, it is good to stay on the previous version.

Comment: Approximately when is the fix coming?

Comment: There is no official release date for this (the dates are Red Hat internal AFAIK). And the time when it gets to CentOS, it is other unknown, but it takes also some time.

Comment: How could i rollback to the previous version of centos? As i've read there is no clean way to rollback from yum updates, also with an update as massive as centos 7.3, i fear i may break more stuff than i'll fix by rolling back...

Comment: Doing `yum downgrade "openssh*"` should do the job. It is still only minor update and it should not cause any troubles.

Comment: I'm getting: `No Match for available package: openssh-askpass-6.6.1p1-31.el7.x86_64
No Match for available package: openssh-keycat-6.6.1p1-31.el7.x86_64
No Match for available package: openssh-ldap-6.6.1p1-31.el7.x86_64
No Match for available package: openssh-server-sysvinit-6.6.1p1-31.el7.x86_64`

Comment: Then you will need to download the packages from 7.2, which are available under http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/Packages/